# Data not fetched from MySQL table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to print the name and last name of an ID entered in the text box. Here is the PHP and HTML code:

```
    <head>
        <title>
            Search your name by ID
        </title>
    </head>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["searchname"]))
{
    $id = $_POST["searchname"]; 
    $connect = new mysqli("localhost","adarsh","Yeah!","adarsh");
    $a = mysql_query("Select * from users where id='$id'",$connect);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($a);
    echo "$row[0] , $row[1] , $row[2]";
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
?>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <input type="text" maxlength="6" name="searchname">
            <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
```

Output when I enter ID:

```
 , ,
```

There are entries in the MySQL table but I am unable to fetch them. What is wrong with my code?

**UPDATE:** I have also tried `mysql_fetch_array` but it is not working.

Comment: mixing mysql and mysqli !!!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to echo the result between the `head` and the `body`? Are you sure that is what you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Main problem is that you're miximg `mysqli` and `mysql`. These are absolutely different APIs.
Assuming you have

```
$id = $_POST["searchname"]; 
$connect = new mysqli("localhost","adarsh","Yeah!","adarsh");
```

Next you should:

```
$result = $connect->query("Select * from users where id='$id'");
```

Then get results:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

And of course, instead of directly putting values into your query use **prepared statements**.

**Update**:
about mistakes:

- Your main mistake is mixing apis. When you use `mysql` (which is deprecated and you **mustn't use it anymore**) you can't use any of `mysqli` functions and vice versa.
- Next - as you create mysqli object with `new`, you should work in object-oriented style, i.e. calling methods from your mysqli object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Search your name by ID
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
            <input type="text" maxlength="6" name="searchname">
            <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["searchname"])){

    $id = $_POST["searchname"]; 
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","adarsh","Yeah!","adarsh");
    $result = mysql_query("Select * from users where id='$id'",$connect);
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    print_R($row);
}else{

    echo "there is something wrong";
}
```